# Cloudformation for Kinesis Firehose delivery into Redshift

Tags: amazon-cloudformation

I am building a Kinesis Firehose Delivery Stream that will stream into Redshift.

This process has an S3 bucket as an intermediary.

The Cloudformation docs for AWS::KinesisFirehose::DeliveryStream state that two required directives are User and Password for a user with INSERT privs into the Redshift cluster.

From here: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/firehose/latest/dev/create-destination.html#create-destination-redshift

> User name An Amazon Redshift user with permissions to access the
>   Amazon Redshift cluster. This user must have the Amazon Redshift
>   INSERT permission for copying data from the S3 bucket to the Amazon
>   Redshift cluster

Should I create this user via Cloudformation? For example, an IAM user? How would an IAM user be granted INSERT permissions here? Also, when spinning up a Firehose stream in the console, the implication from the UI is that this is just a SQL user created with CREATE USER syntax.

So do I need to specify the username and password in the CF stack template, and then use "CREATE USER WITH PASSWORD " SQL directly on the RS cluster after it is up and running?

Doing it this way strikes me as a dependency problem with the stack. (Although there are plenty of things that CF can't do naturally, such as create Route53 records or upload a file into S3, so maybe there's precedent for this)

I can't find any clarification on this and I can't find any CF stack examples that actually use Redshift as a Kinesis Firehose destination.